# Get the updated document after update_one

Tags: mongoengine

What parameter needs to pass for the MongoEngine update_one() to get the updated document in return? Currently, it is returning 0 or 1.

Comment: Instead of using update_one() I used the method modify(). Pass the parameter new = True to it to get the updated result.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using update_one() I used the method modify(). Pass the parameter new = True to it to get the updated result

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mongoengine documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update_one) there doesn't seem to be anything you can pass to `update_one` to return the updated document. I've tried this myself in a test environment and I'm also getting either a 0 or 1 returned.

There is a parameter you can pass to [`update`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update) called `full_result` which gives you a bit more information but it's nothing that would help you in this case.